# Jenkins jar vs dockerfile

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile

I started learning devops recently. Guys  I have  a doubt here please solve. After testing Jenkins package everything including code and dependencies into a war/jar file. Even dockerfile contains application's source code and dependencies.  Now if we are using the docker container to deploy onto production server. Now where do we use the war file that is generated from JEnkins? someone please clarify.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question to represent your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets take Jenkins itself as an example. you can download jenkins.war but still you need a place to host this war file so you can use docker for that. think of it as an alternative for virtual machines.

So the jar file that you have generated through jenkins build needs java or tomcat or whatever external dependencies to be up and running docker can do that for you. Take a look at the following example:

- [Run a Simple .jar Application in a Docker Container](https://dzone.com/articles/run-simple-jar-application-in-docker-container-1)

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the reply and the clarification.

Comment: Hi @Mostafa, Thanks much for clearing this doubt. One more question I have, please clarify. Actually we use ansible for installing configurations on the servers by using ansible yaml file, why can't we use kubernetes for the same, why cant we write those changes in a docker image and then deploy those containers on host machines using Kubernetes.

Comment: When you change your code you need to build a new docker image that can be deployed. kubernetes can be used to manage docker containers in production environment. ansible can be used to deploy the docker containers or you can ignore ansible and use `helm` which is a package manager for kuberentes of course this will be after creating a chart for your application

Comment: Read about each tool on its own to understand the main purpose of it so you don't get confused by all of them. so for example you can use ansible to deploy docker containers as an alternative to docker-compose.yml (in case of using docker itself) and so on